# How can I flatten out data in a list and then get a count of what's in each column using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a LINQ report but having difficulty.

I want to first of all create a select on each row that put numbers into different columns and that seems to work.  But then I want to get a count of those and when I run the query every column has the same value.

Here is what I am tried:

```
var AppVersion = CreateExcelFile.ListToDataTable(Start
            .Where(x => x.DeviceName != "Richard iPhone 11")
            .Where(x => x.IsPhysical == true)
            .Select(x => new AppVersionModel
            {
                DateYYMMDD = x.DateYYMMDD,
                Android043 = x.IsAndroid == true && x.AppVersion == "0.4.3" ? 1 : 0,
                Android044 = x.IsAndroid == true && x.AppVersion == "0.4.4" ? 1 : 0,
                Android050 = x.IsAndroid == true && x.AppVersion == "0.5.0" ? 1 : 0,
                IOS043 = x.IsIos == true && x.AppVersion == "0.4.3" ? 1 : 0,
                IOS044 = x.IsIos == true && x.AppVersion == "0.4.4" ? 1 : 0,
                IOS050 = x.IsIos == true && x.AppVersion == "0.5.0" ? 1 : 0,
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.DateYYMMDD)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .Select(g => new AppVersionModel
            {
                DateYYMMDD = g.Key,
                Android043 = g.Count(),
                Android044 = g.Count(),
                Android050 = g.Count(),
                IOS043 = g.Count(),
                IOS044 = g.Count(),
                IOS050 = g.Count()
            })
            .ToList());
```

Can someone give me advice on what I might be doing wrong.

Here is some sample data

```
Date      IsAndroid   IsIOS   AppVersion
01012020  true        false   0.4.4
01012020  true        false   0.4.3
01012020  true        false   0.4.4
01012020  false       true    0.4.3
01012020  false       true    0.4.3
01012020  false       true    0.4.4
```

Desired output

```
Date      Android043  Android044  IOS043   IOS044

01012020      1           2         2         1
```

Comment: Post sample data and desired output.

Comment: I added some sample date.  Let me know if it doesn't make sense.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Count` function just:

> Returns the number of elements in a sequence.

What you want to do is count the number of items in the sequence that match a certain condition. For that use the [override the accepts a predicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__):

```
.Select(g => new AppVersionModel {
    DateYYMMDD = g.Key,
    Android043 = g.Count(i => i.Android043 == 1),
    Android044 = g.Count(i => i.Android044 == 1),
    // ....
})
```

As you made sure the properties have 0,1 values you could also just use `Sum`:

```
.Select(g => new AppVersionModel {
    DateYYMMDD = g.Key,
    Android043 = g.Sum(i => i.Android043),
    Android044 = g.Sum(i => i.Android044),
    // ....
})
```

---

However I'd go with a different approach of having the properties store booleans as seen below. In addition no need to write `x.BOOLEAN_PROPERTY == true`, just write `x.BOOLEAN_PROPERTY`.

```
.Select(x => new AppVersionModel {
    DateYYMMDD = x.DateYYMMDD,
    Android043 = x.IsAndroid && x.AppVersion == "0.4.3",
    Android044 = x.IsAndroid && x.AppVersion == "0.4.4",
    Android050 = x.IsAndroid && x.AppVersion == "0.5.0",
    IOS043 = x.IsIos && x.AppVersion == "0.4.3",
    IOS044 = x.IsIos && x.AppVersion == "0.4.4",
    IOS050 = x.IsIos && x.AppVersion == "0.5.0",
})
.GroupBy(x => x.DateYYMMDD)
.OrderBy(g => g.Key)
.Select(g => new AppVersionModel {
    DateYYMMDD = g.Key,
    Android043 = g.Count(i => i.Android043),
    Android044 = g.Count(i => i.Android44),
    // ...
})
```